# Git merge the contents between branches among two repositories

Tags: git, gitlab

I have two git repository with the following structure:

Repo A --> develop

Repo B --> master

I want to merge the branch **master** of **Repo B** into branch **develop** of **Repo A**.

Can any please suggest ?

Comment: Are those repos based on the same common history?

Comment: No the repos do not have the common history

Comment: develop and master are branches right? not folder?

Comment: While they have no common history, would it make sense to put all commits of master on top of develop?

Answer (score 0):

Well basically you can add two remotes in the same repository and work normally.

```
git remote add A <repo A url>
git remote add B <repo B url>
```

Make a new branch for merging based on A develop

```
git checkout -b merger A/develop
```

Merge and resolve conflicts

```
git merge B/master
```

If successful, push to A or wherever

```
git push A merger:develop
```

Comment: After `git remote add B`, do we need to fetch the master from B  ?

Answer (score 0):

go to branch develop: git checkout develop

pull the changes in master into develop: git merge master

push the changes in develop: git push origin develop